# comparative phrase with put together

Tags: grammar

> "Comb your hair!" he barked, by way of a morning greeting.
>    About once a week, Uncle Vernon looked over the top of his newspaper
>   and shouted that Harry needed a haircut. Harry must have had more
>   haircuts ***than the rest of the boys in his class put together***,
>   but it made no difference, his hair simply grew that way - all over
>   the place.
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

1. Is there ‘*have had haircuts*’ omitted between *boys* and *in his class*?
2. Is ‘*put together*’ a participial phrase modifying boys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding 1) No, the sentence is fine as is.  Regarding 2) I am not sure, but I think not; what is meant here is putting together all the haircuts not all the boys. That is, if you counted all the haircuts of all the other boys and compared that to Harry's haircuts, the latter would be higher.